# Getting bootstrap 2 button styling in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I really liked the look & feel of `btn btn-primary` buttons in bootstrap 2 . I'm using bootstrap 3, and I don't like the flat look. I tried adding `bootstrap-theme.css`, which came long with bootstrap 3. But still its not the same.

Bootstrap 2 button:

[image]

Bootstrap 3 button:

[image]

Comment: create an override css file, containing everything related to .btn (including the color variants such as btn-primary, btn-danger, and so on) from bs v2 and place it under bs v3 css.

Comment: @AzDesign: Yeah, that could be done. But I was hoping for a litte more  cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@AzDesign](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938885/azdesign) suggested, you want to copy the relevant css from BS 2 and use this as an override in your custom CSS. Here's a working example of BSv2 primary button styling in BS v3: 
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/39zmy/

Good luck!

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn.active,
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled] {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  *background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  background-color: #cccccc \9;
}

.btn:first-child {
  *margin-left: 0;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-position: 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
     -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
       -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
          transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.btn.active,
.btn:active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.btn-primary.active,
.btn-warning.active,
.btn-danger.active,
.btn-success.active,
.btn-info.active,
.btn-inverse.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #006dcc;
  *background-color: #0044cc;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0044cc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0044cc);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #0044cc #0044cc #002a80;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0044cc', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0044cc;
  *background-color: #003bb3;
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active {
  background-color: #003399 \9;
}
```